# Primefaces confirmDialog does nothing in actionListener

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a `comandButton` which calls to a `confirmDialog` which  must eliminate a user, but it never calls  method that there is in its actionListener.

This is the code:

```
<p:dialog id="dialogEditar" widgetVar="dialogEditar" header="#{bundle_usuarios.usuarios_titulo_edicion}" resizable="false">
    <p:panelGrid id="panelEditar"
        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                <p:commandButton id="btModificar" type="submit" actionListener="#{usuariosMB.modificarUsuario()}"
                             value="#{bundle_general.general_modificar}" update="formEditar" rendered="#{usuariosMB.permisoCtMenu}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column colspan="7">
                <p:commandButton id="btEliminar" type="button" onclick="confirmation.show()"
                              value="#{bundle_general.general_eliminar}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
    </p:panelGrid>
    <p:confirmDialog appendToBody="true" id="confirmDialog" message="#{bundle_usuarios.usuarios_confirma}"
                     header="#{bundle_usuarios.usuarios_titulo_confirma_eliminar}" severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmation">
        <p:commandButton id="confirm" type="submit" value="#{bundle_usuarios.usuarios_aceptar_eliminar}"
                         update="dialogEditar, formEditar" oncomplete="confirmation.hide()"
                         actionListener="#{usuariosMB.eliminarUsuario()}" rendered="#{usuariosMB.permisoCtMenu}" /> 
        <p:commandButton id="decline" value="#{bundle_usuarios.general_cancelar}" onclick="confirmation.hide()" type="button" />
    </p:confirmDialog>
</p:dialog>
```

If i put the same code, without confirmDialog, it runs and deletes the user without problems.

The code that runs with success is the next:

```
<p:dialog id="dialogEditar" widgetVar="dialogEditar" header="#{bundle_usuarios.usuarios_titulo_edicion}" resizable="false">
    <p:panelGrid id="panelEditar"
        <p:row>
            <p:column>
                <p:commandButton id="btModificar" type="submit" actionListener="#{usuariosMB.modificarUsuario()}"
                             value="#{bundle_general.general_modificar}" update="formEditar" rendered="#{usuariosMB.permisoCtMenu}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column colspan="7">
                 <p:commandButton id="btEliminar" type="submit" actionListener="#{usuariosMB.eliminarUsuario()}" value="#{bundle_general.general_eliminar}" update="dialogEditar, formEditar" rendered="#{usuariosMB.permisoCtMenu}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:row>
    </p:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>
```

Another thing, when I click on the commandButon with id="confirm", the confirmDialog never dissapear and it stays blocked in the window.

If you need more details, say me which require.
Please, any suggestion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your dialog placed in a h:form it is a good exercise to carry out from this form and place a h:form inside the dialog. Still you would be able to access via widgetVar

```
<h:form>
....
</h:form>

<p:dialog>

<h:form>
...
<p:commandButton />
<h:form>

</p:dialog>
```

Comment: I will see my code tomorrow, sorry, but I had to do other things and I couldn't check it. Thanks!

Comment: This is my error, thanks you friend, and sorry to answer you too later. :S

Answer (score 3):

Change the command button to a normal button

```
<p:commandButton id="confirm" type="submit" value="Your Command Text"/>
```

Then on the click event call the dialog

```
<p:commandButton id="confirm" type="button" value="Your Command Text" onclick="dialog.show()"/>
```

`dialog` is the `widget var` of your dialog.

Then you can perform your delete operation from a command button inside the confirm dialog.

Looks like you already did this change. You are still getting the same issue?

Comment: I just try it, but I have the same result.

Comment: Then you must be missing forms as answered by HRgiger. Make sure you dont put form inside a form.